# Python, Matplotlib: How to set the axis range when x is time?

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, range, axis

I am doing my school Arduino project at home, and the teacher asks me to visualize my data for him. On my x-axis, I have more than 20K time points need to show, and I try to set a range for it.

The graph I am trying to achieve:
[image: desired graph]

What I got up till now:
[image: current graph]

It is very clear I am doing something wrong, and I have researched for a way to solve it.

The # part of my plotting part is what I learned from the internet, but they do not work here.

Please help me and if anything in question is unclear, let me know!

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

header = []
data = []

path="DATALOG.csv"   #CHANGE filename to match file
file = open(path, newline='')
reader=csv.reader(file)

header=next(reader) #This reads the first row and stores the words in header.
data=[row for row in reader]  #This reads the rest and store the data in a list

file.close()  #closes the file when complete

# This function will print the headings with their index. Helpful when dealing with many columns
def print_header():
   for index, column_header in enumerate(header):
       print(index, column_header)

# I want the high and low temperatures in New Glasgow for June 2010
# Key headings
# 0 date/time
# 1 temperature
# 2 humidity %
# 3 light level%

days = []
light = []

for row in range (len(data)):
    day = data[row][0]
    lights = data[row][3]
    current_date=datetime.strptime(data[row][0], "%A %H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y")

    light.append(float(lights))        #store the day’s high temp in list
          #store the day’s low temp in list
    days.append(str(day))

fig = plt.figure(dpi=128, figsize = (50, 6))

#x = [dc[0] for dc in days]

#xticks = range(0,len(x),10)
#xlabels=[x[index] for index in xticks]
#xticks.append(len(x))
#xlabels.append(days[-1][0])
#ax.set_xticks(xtick)
#ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels,rotation=40)

plt.plot(days,light,c = 'red',label = 'temprature')

plt.title("LIGHT")
plt.xlabel('days',fontsize = 5)
#ax.plot(np.arange('Wednesday 12:00:00 08/01/2020',' Thursday 11:58:10 09/01/2020'), range(10))
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.ylabel('light (%)', fontsize = 12)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize = 10)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.savefig('plot.png')
```

Comment: Are you looking for a solution using r ? If so, can you provide a small reproducible example of your dataset ? (see how to do it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer if you review the [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and modify your question.

Comment: Thanks for responding to me ! It is really hard for me to explain my idea because I am a python rookie and an English learner!

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of how you can plot your data using `r`:

As you did not provide a reproducible example, I created a fake one using my understanding of your code. Basically, it looks that you have a file with 4 columns: Days, Temperature, Humidity and Light_levels. Here, I only create two columns.

```r
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Day = as.character(seq.Date(from = as.Date("2019-01-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d"), to =as.Date("2019-02-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d"), by = "days" )),
                 Light_levels = sample(0:100,32, replace = TRUE))
```

The datafame `df` should looks like:

```r
> head(df)
         Day Light_levels
1 2019-01-01           30
2 2019-01-02           78
3 2019-01-03           50
4 2019-01-04           13
5 2019-01-05           66
6 2019-01-06           41
```

I think your issue came from the management of date format. In `r`, it's pretty common that when you import a csv file as a dataframe, it will convert dates in a factor or character format.

You can check by looking at the structure of the dataframe by using `str` function:

```r
> str(df)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Day         : Factor w/ 32 levels "2019-01-01","2019-01-02",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Light_levels: int  30 78 50 13 66 41 49 42 100 13 ...
```

So, to use dates in a date format, you need to convert this factor format into a date format using:

```r
df$Day = as.Date(df$Day, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Now, if you check the structure of `df`, you will see:

```r
str(df)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Day         : Date, format: "2019-01-01" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-03" ...
 $ Light_levels: int  30 78 50 13 66 41 49 42 100 13 ...
```

Now, you can plot it with the package `ggplot2`(you have ton install `ggplot2` first):

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Day, y = Light_levels))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "days", date_labels = "%b %d")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

and get the following plot:
[image]

You can adjust the display of each dates by playing with arguments of `scale_x_date` (see more information here: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html)

Alternatively, without to install `ggplot2` package, you can do it using `base` R `plot` function:

```r
plot(x = df$Day, y = df$Light_levels, type = "l", xaxt = "n", xlab = "")
axis.Date(1,at=seq(min(df$Day), max(df$Day), by="days"), format="%b %d")
```

[image]

Hope it will help you to figure it out how to plot your data.

Comment: Hello dc37!  Whoa, it is really a very complex `r` code!  I am afraid I am not able to understand r at this point in time, but I very much appreciate your response!  Thank you for your explaination again!

Comment: You're welcome! But it is not a really difficult code, when you will get into R, you will find it quite easy actually. There is a lot of tutorial online that can help you to start with